# Constraining eager loaded relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I found a very bizarre behavior of `with` function for overloading relationships. I have `Product` and `Deal` relationships, such that `Product` `belongsTo()` `Deal` (through `product_id` in `deals` table). Now, when I try to get all products on sale:

```
Product::with(['deal' => function($query) {
    $query->whereDate('ends_at', '>', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
}])->get()
```

this returns a collection of **all** products, even though there are **no** records in `deals` table and **all** products have `deal_id` set to `NULL`. At the same time `Product::has('deal')->get()` returns an empty collection, as you would expect.

I initially discovered this problem while trying to fetch five random products on sale together with `Deal` and `Image` relationships:

```
Product::with(['deal' => function ($query) {
        $query->whereDate('ends_at', '>', // promo still active
                             Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
    },
    'images' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('featured', true);    // image featured on homepage
    }])
->where('status', 'IN_STOCK')   // 'In Stock'
->whereNull('deleted_at')       // wasn't soft-deleted
->orderByRaw('RAND()')
->take(5)->get())
```

This yields a collection with 5 random `Product`s out of all `Product`s. I tried with `query->whereNotNull('ends_at')->whereDate('ends_at' ..... );` but got same results.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of the concept is completely wrong here.

If you are saying that a **Product** `belongsTo()` **Deal**, then lets assume that a **Deal** `hasMany()` **Products**.

This is the deals table

```
deals
id | name | ends_at | blah | blah

products
id | deal_id | name | blah | blah
```

So basically, the `Product::with('deal')` should return you all products with their Deals being Eager loaded. But `Deal::with('products')` will return you an empty collection, since no products have a valid `deal_id` in it.

It is important to note that, since **Product** can only `belongTo` a single **Deal**, you will always get the Deal Model rather than a collection when you perform `Product::with('deal')` query. But when you perform `Deal::with('products')` you are bound to get a collection.

So basically, when you say

This returns a collection of all products, even though there are no records in deals table and all products have deal_id set to NULL.

**It is pretty obvious**.... because the query here is being done on Products and not Deal. If you are trying to find the **Deal** where `ends_at > Carbon::now()`, you'll have to do this.

```
Deal::with('product')->where('ends_at', '>', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `with` then it only eager loads the relations on the constraints provided but if you want to filter the parent model by their relations then `whereHas` is your friend. So your query should be as:

```
Product::whereHas('deal' => function($query) {
          $query->whereDate('ends_at', '>', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
        })->get();
```

Now it will fetch only those `Product` which satisfy the given constraint.

You can also use the combination of `with` and `whereHas` as:

```
Product::whereHas('deal' => function($query) {
          $query->whereDate('ends_at', '>', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
        })
        ->with(['deal' => function($query) {
            $query->whereDate('ends_at', '>', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
        }])
        ->get();
```