# Laravel search by filter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

Below is my json for product detail with its features.

```
{
"id": 1,
"title": "Moto g4 plus",
"description": "3 GB RAM | 32 GB ROM | Expandable Upto 128 GB\r\n5.5 inch Display\r\n16MP Rear Camera | 5MP Front Camera\r\n3000 mAh Battery",
"price": "14999.00",
"featured_image": "featured_image/qzHWpQeSfKjZ6DOS59ROyYboJ1GCvVi6NNVfLtVV.jpeg",
"category_id": 1,
"brand_id": 4,
"created_at": "2017-07-13 14:59:53",
"updated_at": "2017-07-13 15:07:49",
"deleted_at": null,
"features": [
                {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "RAM",
                "parent_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2017-07-02 17:42:36",
                "updated_at": "2017-07-02 17:42:36",
                "default_value": "",
                "pivot": {
                "product_id": 1,
                "feature_id": 3,
                "value": "3"
                   }
                },
                {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "Expandable memory",
                "parent_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2017-07-05 15:43:29",
                "updated_at": "2017-07-05 15:43:29",
                "default_value": "",
                "pivot": {
                "product_id": 1,
                "feature_id": 10,
                "value": "32"
                    }
                },
}
```

now i want filter search as per features for e.g want phone with RAM of 4GB and expandable memory of 64Gb.
and i want result as per my all filter and give me accurate result as per dropdown select.
Below screenshot for dropdown how user select features.
[image: screenshot]

Below is my database table for product and pivot for product feature
[image: Product]
[image: product_feature]
As above table how i stored my product and its features with product value.

Below is my model code

```
public function features()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Feature')->withPivot('value');
}
```

Contoller.php

```
function searchedFeatures(Request $request)
{
    return $products = Product::with(['features' => function($q){
        $q->where('name','=','ram');
        $q->where('name','=','operating system');
    }])->get();
}
```

This will give me result blank feature array and i want to check feature name and its value for e.g product have ram of 4gb or product have expandable memory 32Gb etc and result in array of all match products.

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the request values to filter the query result?

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi i want selected value from dropdown filtered from json array and give me result for e.g if i select ram 4Gb from dropdown then matched product who have 4gb ram give me in result and in pivot value is value of feature like ram.

Comment: @Nileshsingh, could you show what you receive as a request in your controller when you select that dropdown?

Comment: You should be using `whereHas` instead of `with`. I fell in [this trap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203604/constraining-eager-loaded-relationship) too a while ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying so many thing and r&d i found solution using DB query by self joining table as below function. If any one have better solution please share here.

```
function searchedFeatures(Request $request)
{
    $ram = Feature::where('name','ram')->first();
    $processor = Feature::where('name','processor technology')->first();
    $screen = Feature::where('name','screen size')->first();
    $battery = Feature::where('name','battery capacity')->first();
    $os = Feature::where('name','operating system')->first();
    $mainCamera = Feature::where('name','main camera')->first();
    $selfieCamera = Feature::where('name','selfie camera')->first();
    $price = Feature::where('name','price')->first();
    //return $request->all();
    $products = DB::table('products AS p')
                ->select('p.id','p.title','p.price','p.featured_image','r.value AS ram','pro.value as processor','s.value AS screen','b.value AS battery','os.value AS os','mc.value AS main_camera','sc.value AS selfie_camera')
                ->leftJoin('feature_product as r','r.product_id','=','p.id')
                ->leftJoin('feature_product as pro','pro.product_id','=','p.id')
                ->leftJoin('feature_product as s','s.product_id','=','p.id')
                ->leftJoin('feature_product as b','b.product_id','=','p.id')
                ->leftJoin('feature_product as os','os.product_id','=','p.id')
                ->leftJoin('feature_product as mc','mc.product_id','=','p.id')
                ->leftJoin('feature_product as sc','sc.product_id','=','p.id')
                ->where('r.feature_id','=',$ram->id)
                ->where('pro.feature_id','=',$processor->id)
                ->where('s.feature_id','=',$screen->id)
                ->where('b.feature_id','=',$battery->id)
                ->where('os.feature_id','=',$os->id)
                ->where('mc.feature_id','=',$mainCamera->id)
                ->where('sc.feature_id','=',$selfieCamera->id)
                ->where('r.value','LIKE',isset($request->ram)? $request->ram:NULL)
                ->where('pro.value','LIKE',isset($request->processor)?$request->processor.'-core':NULL)
                ->whereBetween('s.value',isset($request->screen)?(explode(',', $request->screen)):[1,100] )
                ->whereBetween('b.value',isset($request->battery)?(explode(',', $request->battery)):[1000,5000] )
                ->where('os.value','LIKE',isset($request->os)? $request->os:NULL)
                ->whereBetween('mc.value',isset($request->main_camera)?(explode(',', $request->main_camera)):[2,50] )
                ->whereBetween('sc.value',isset($request->selfie_camera)?(explode(',', $request->selfie_camera)):[2,50] )
                ->whereBetween('p.price',isset($request->price)?(explode(',', $request->price)):[1000,80000] )
                ->get();
    $categoryPage=true;                    
    return view('product.searched',compact(['products','categoryPage']));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `orWhere()` method, this should be the missing part of your query

```
return $products = Product::with(['features' => function($q){
    $q->where('name','=','ram')
      ->orWhere('os','=','operating system');
}])->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the input you send instead of directly setting the where statements.

```
function searchedFeatures(Request $request)
{
    return $products = Product::with(['features' => function($q){
        $q->where('name','=',$request->ram);
        $q->where('os','=',$request->operating_system);
    }])->get();
}
```

If its returning nothing its likely that it is not matching what it is in the Database. Are you sure the values entered are correct and similar to what is in the DB?